# JQuery .parent() not finding correct parent

Tags: jquery

When I do :

> $(evt.target).parent().parent()

it will correctly give me an element "tr".
However when I do

> $(evt.target).parent("tr")

it will not find the parent "tr".

Id like to make my design not depend on the structure of the HTML.

Is there a reason as to why it is not finding?

Comment: $(evt.target).parent().parent() is 2 nodes up, but .parent find only 1 up. So .parent(tr) find 1 node up and must be tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation a little bit more carefully.

You have to use the .parents() function.

So, the solution would be :

> $(evt.target).parents("tr")

Comment: `.parents()` might not be what you are looking for. If you have a structure like `ul > li.liA  > ul > li.liB  > a.aClass` and you do `$('.aClass').parents('li')` you will get both the `.liB` and the `.liA`  with `$('.aClass').closest('li')` you will only get `.liB` as result.

Answer (score 0):

`$(evt.target).parent("tr")`  will give you all the elements that are `parent` (not ancestor) of the jQuery resultset `$(evt.target)` and have the `tagName` `tr`.

`$(evt.target).parent().parent()` is not the parent of `evt.target` but an `ancestor`.

You are looking for [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(evt.target).closest("tr")
```

You should read about the different of `Parent <> Child` and `Ancestor <> Descendant`